# Serpinski triangle count - all possibilities

Tags: geometry

Correct title should be probably "How many parallelograms (horizontally flipped too) can be found in equilateral triangle ?"

I'm trying to find a formula to determine number of all visible triangles of every size (if set so). Input *n* = number of smallest triangles creating 1 side of the biggest one. Output *c*. Manually checked first 20 inputs, counts for first 8:

n  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    ...

c  1    5    13   26   47   72   118  170  ...

Got some sort of formula but it seems too complex, I believe it can be done simpler.

Comment: What does one with n = 3 look like?

Comment: please check http://www.erepublik.com/en/article/-wolf-quiz-time--2331636/1/20

Comment: equilateral triangle, figure 1, the left one is n=2, right one n=3\